# Related to then 12th Derivative of This Integral

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f(x) = \int_0^x \cos(t^3+x-xt)dt.$ I am trying to
    figure out the value of $f^{(12)}(1) + f^{(10)}(1)$ where $f^n$ is the
    $n$th derivative of the function $f$. My teacher recommended that I
    first compute $f''(x) + f'(x)$ first and use that to consider what to do
    with the previous derivative addition.

I assume that the first place would be to try and solve for
    $f'(x)$ By simplifying out $f(x).$ I can see from our method that
    given our interpretation of the antiderivative,
    $f'(x) = \cos(x^3+x-x^2) - \cos(0+x-0) = \cos(x^3-x^2+x) - \cos(x).$ Hence,
    $f''(x) = \sin(x)-\sin(x^3-x^2+x)(3x^2-2x+1).$ However, I am now having
    some difficulty figuring out how to relate the summation of the two
    of these to $f^{(12)}(x)+f^{(10)}(x).$ Any suggestions? Would it be
    reasonable to just brute force finding these derivatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

the function inside the integral sign is a function of both $x$ and $t$, let us call it $g(x,t)=\cos(t^3+x-xt)$. Then
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x g(x,t) \, dt=\int_0^x \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \, dt + g(x,x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(x)-g(x,0)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(0).$$

So in your case
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=-\int_0^x \sin(t^3+x-xt)(1-t) \, dt+\cos(x^3+x-x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

No. Your first derivate is wrong. Let $g:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $given by $g(t,x)=\cos(t^3+x-xt)$ By Generalized Leibniz Rule

$\begin{eqnarray}\dfrac{d}{dx}f(x)&=&\dfrac{d}{dx}\int_0^x\cos(t^3+x-xt)dt\\&=&g(x,x)+\int_0^x\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t,x)dt\\
&=&\cos(x^3+x-x^2)-\int_0^x\sin(t^3+x-xt)(1-t)dt
\end{eqnarray}$

and

$\begin{eqnarray}&&\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}f(x)\\&=&-(3x^2+1-2x)\sin(x^3+x-x^2)-\sin(x^3+x-x^2)(1-x)-\int_0^x(1-t)^2\cos(t^3+x-tx)dt\\
&=&-(3x^2+2-3x)\sin(x^3+x-x^2)-\int_0^x(1-t)^2\cos(t^3+x-tx)dt
\end{eqnarray}$